# Plot countplot for two or more column on single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataFrame, df:

```
Sno | Attribute_1   | Attribute_2   | Attribute_3
__________________________________________________
1   | option_1      | option_3      |option_2
2   | option_1      | option_1      |option_1
3   | option_2      | option_2      |option_2
4   | option_1      | option_1      |option_3
5   | option_3      | option_2      |option_2
6   | option_3      | option_3      |option_1
7   | option_1      | option_3      |option_2
```

Here Attribute_1, Attribute_2 and Attribute_3 contains categorical data - option_1 or option_2 or option_3 for each of the rows.

I want to create a count plot on the same plot for all the attributes.
I am able to do it for one column by:

```
sns.countplot(x="Attribute_1", data=df);
```

I can individually create for each of the attributes, but what I am looking for it that on the same plot I can have count plot for all the attributes.
i.e X-axis will have attributes, and each attribute will have three count plot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seaborn usually works best with long form datasets. I.e. instead of 3 columns with different options for each attribute you would have two columns, one for the options and one for the attributes. This can easily be created via `pd.melt`. Then the `hue` value can be used on the "options" column:

```
sns.countplot(x="variable", hue="value", data=pd.melt(df))
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

a= np.random.choice(["option_{}".format(i) for i in [1,2,3]], size=(12,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["Attribute_{}".format(i) for i in list("ABC")])

sns.countplot(x="variable", hue="value", data=pd.melt(df))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Equally you can interchange `x` and `hue`:

```
sns.countplot(x="value", hue="variable", data=pd.melt(df))
```

[image]