# How can i join these 2 graphs into 1 graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-analysis

My variables are start_hour and end_hour. I made 2 graphs, with the same code just changing the start_hour and end_hour variables. How can I join them into 1 graph to compare? I can't use hue because it's not categorical variables. But I would like to use colour to differentiate the start and end hours on 1 graph

```
base_color = sb.color_palette()[0]
hour_order = np.arange(0,24)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.title('Bike Service Popular Times')
ax = sb.countplot(data=gobike, x='start_hour', order=hour_order, color = base_color)

plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Start hours');
```

[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5susZ.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code. In your case, minimal is not the problem. You've reduced the code to what was pertinent for your question. But it is not reproducible. We don't know what ``sb`` is (I surmise it is seaborn, but it would be easier with your import).  And what gobike is. A dataframe I also surmise (else why the "pandas" tag)

Comment: Basically, you are asking how to plot seaborn countplot with multiple columns, correct? If so, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223224/matplotlib-plot-countplot-for-two-or-more-column-on-single-plot